# beginner's: const definition in Redux confusing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

In this introductory course of Redux
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-store-methods-getstate-dispatch-and-subscribe?series=getting-started-with-redux, the presenter says that the following two lines are identical

```
const { createStore } = Redux;
var createStore = Redux.createStore;
```

I've just searched for ES6 `const` documentation, and it does not quite answer my question, how are these two lines identical?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I wanted to ask the exact same thing and ran into this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not related to `const` (which is just a way to define a constant), but instead to [object destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/).

So these are all identical:

```
var createStore = Redux.createStore;
const { createStore: createStore } = Redux;
const { createStore } = Redux;
```

In the line `const { createStore: createStore } = Redux;`, the first `createStore` defines the property of `Redux` to get. The second `createStore` defines the name under which is available after the declaration.

In addition, in ES6 defining objects like `{ name: name }` can be shortened to `{ name }`.